# Split one react component into two

Tags: reactjs

I would like to know how I should split this code into two separate components.

```
 import React from "react";

const DropdownMenu = (props) => {
  const DropdownItem = (props) => {
    return (
      <a href="#" className="menu-item">
        <span className="icon-button">{props.rightIcon}</span>
        {props.children}
      </a>
    );
  };
  return (
    <div className="dropdown">
      <DropdownItem>{props.companyName[0].name}</DropdownItem>
      <DropdownItem>{props.companyName[1].name}</DropdownItem>
      <DropdownItem>Settings</DropdownItem>
      <DropdownItem>Testing</DropdownItem>
      <DropdownItem>Get our App</DropdownItem>
      <DropdownItem>Mobile</DropdownItem>
      <DropdownItem>Log out</DropdownItem>
    </div>
  );
};
export default DropdownMenu;
```

I try to split them up by myself but then my dropdown menu breaks and instead of opening a container down, it opens container inside my navbar, I think the issue with `{props.children}` but I don't know exactly how to fix it.

After splitting components I want it to remain like on this screenshot

[image]

Comment: Just create a new component with the function exactly same as `DropdownItem` function

Comment: and pass the `props` to `DropdownItem` i.e `rightIcon`

Comment: `props.rightIcon` coming from which component `props` i.e `DropdownMenu` or `DropdownItem`. Because you've used both parameter as `props`

Comment: `props.rightIcon` shouldn't it be undefined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is 2 problems with your code.

well first, don't ever create a component inside render function of another component.

second and root cause of your problem is you have 2 variables named "props" in same scope

```
const DropdownItem = (props) => {
    return (
      <a href="#" className="menu-item">
        <span className="icon-button">{props.rightIcon}</span>}
        {props.children}
      </a>
    );
  };


const DropdownMenu = (props) => {
  return (
    <div className="dropdown">
      <DropdownItem>{props.companyName[0].name}</DropdownItem>
      <DropdownItem>{props.companyName[1].name}</DropdownItem>
      <DropdownItem>Settings</DropdownItem>
      <DropdownItem>Testing</DropdownItem>
      <DropdownItem>Get our App</DropdownItem>
      <DropdownItem>Mobile</DropdownItem>
      <DropdownItem>Log out</DropdownItem>
    </div>
  );
};
export default DropdownMenu
```

that should fix it.

Comment: in current example yes, but you can add it easy `<DropdownItem rightIcon={<i className="fa fa-user" />}>Settings</DropdownItem>` for example

Answer (score 0):

you should pass rightIcon to every DropdownItem component that it`s passed to it and better to named your props instead of passing them as children

first component:

```
const DropdownItem = ({ label, rightIcon=' ', href='' }) => {
  return (
    <a href={href} className="menu-item">
      <span className="icon-button">{rightIcon}</span>
      {label}
    </a>
  );
};
```

second component:

```
const DropdownMenu = (props) => {
return (
    <div className="dropdown">
      <DropdownItem
        label={props?.companyName?.[0]?.name}
        rightIcon="icon-name"
        href="href for this item"
      />
      <DropdownItem label={props?.companyName?.[1]?.name} rightIcon="second-icon-name"/>
      <DropdownItem label="Settings" />
      <DropdownItem label="Testing" />
      <DropdownItem label="Get our App" />
      <DropdownItem label="Mobile" />
      <DropdownItem label="Log out" rightIcon='log-out-icon'/>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: why not just `({children,rightIcon=' ', href=''})` ?